# How to do double comparison on a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need compare one column LeadDate (datatype is datetime ) to the values saved in another table (named EmployeeWorkTime). The format of the LeadDate column is like this "2006-08-08 11:50:51. 000".

The employeeworktime table is like this:

```
SyStaffId       Associate Name           Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday Thursday   Friday    Saturday        Sunday
34128           Natasha Dawson            0919      0918      0920      0918      0918      WKEND           WKEND    
34169           Elaine Bueno              0918      1019      0918      1019      0918      WKEND           WKEND    
34385           Aida Rodriguez            0918      1019      0918      1019      0918      WKEND           WKEND    
34419           Sy Lim                    1019      1019      1019      1019      0918      WKEND           WKEND
```

I created a view and included all the fields I need for the comparison. The new view is as in the attachment. But when I want to compare the lead time to the values in the time columns. I had some difficulties. Since the leadday is different, they are in column DayofWeekName, and I want to compare the leadtime to only one column which is the same as the lead day. how could I do that?

For example, for the first lead, the dayofweekname is Thursay, and i want to copmare the leadtime which is the leadhour column to the Thursday column, how could I write code to achieve it.

Thank you very much.

The commands used for creating the new view:

```
Create View dbo.cstAdmissionDailyReportLeadCount_jy
AS
SELECT     dbo.syStudent.AmRepID, dbo.syStudent.LeadDate, DATEPART(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) AS DayofWeekNumber, DATEPART(hh, syStudent.LeadDate)
                      AS LeadHour, dbo.EmployeeWorkTime.[Associate Name], DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) AS DayofWeekName, EmployeeWorkTime.Monday,
                      EmployeeWorkTime.Tuesday, EmployeeWorkTime.Wednesday, EmployeeWorkTime.Thursday, EmployeeWorkTime.Friday,
                      EmployeeWorkTime.Saturday, EmployeeWorkTime.Sunday, CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, syStudent.LeadDate)
                      < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CountAsEffectiveLead
FROM         dbo.syStudent INNER JOIN
                      dbo.EmployeeWorkTime ON dbo.syStudent.AmRepID = dbo.EmployeeWorkTime.SyStaffId
```

Answer (score 0):

Does adding this to your select clause help?

```
case when DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) = "Monday" then EmployeeWorkTime.Monday
when DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) = "Tuesday" then EmployeeWorkTime.Tuesday
when DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) = "Wednesday" then EmployeeWorkTime.Wednesday
when DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) = "Thursday" then EmployeeWorkTime.Thursday
when DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) = "Friday" then EmployeeWorkTime.Friday
when DATENAME(dw, syStudent.LeadDate) = "Saturday" then EmployeeWorkTime.Saturday
else EmployeeWorkTime.Sunday end as ewt_day
```